# Create a sentence out of a list

Tags: python, list, function, return, tuples

User input two city name and create list like `my_list = ["Dallas","SanJose"]` then the following function should return:

```
"You would like to visit Dallas as city 1 and SanJose as city 2 on your trip"
```

This is my code:

```
def CreateSentence(my_list):
    sentence = "You will like to visit "
    for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
           sentence = sentence + item, "as city",i+1,"and"
           return sentence
```

My return is currently `('You would like to visit Dallas' , 'as city', 1 , 'and')`  I am missing the second city.

Comment: have you printed out `my_list` to make sure that the data is actually there?

Comment: Of course that's what it does because you are doing a 'return' in your for loop after the first iteration

Comment: Hi Jay,
Thanks for you update.  Yes I print out my_list and looks like this:
['dalls','sanjose']

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression to gather the list of cities and numbers. Then use `format` to create the inner repeating part of the string. Then you can use `format` again to add the first and last part respectively.

```
def CreateSentence(l):
    middle = ' and '.join('{} as city {}'.format(city, num+1) for num,city in enumerate(l))
    return 'You would like to visit {} on your trip'.format(middle)

>>> my_list = ["Dallas","SanJose"]
>>> CreateSentence(my_list)
'You would like to visit Dallas as city 1 and SanJose as city 2 on your trip'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in method for this, `format()`.

```
>>> string = 'Hi my name is {}, and I am {}'
>>> print(string.format('Ian', 29))
'Hi my name is Ian, and I am 29`
```

Comment: This will get them towards their solution, but is not the complete answer. This does not make a complete sentence when they are iterating through a list.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop, you will need to place the return statement outside the loop so you don't exit the loop prematurely. I also added an if statement to only print the beginning of the sentence once, adding the multiple cities afterwards when the loop is not on "my_list" first item.

```
>>def CreateSentence(my_list):
  sentence = "You will like to visit "
  for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
      if i == 0:
          sentence = sentence + item + " as city " + str(i+1)
      else:
          sentence += " and " + item + " as city " + str(i+1)
  return sentence


>>my_list = ["Atlanta", "NewYork", "Portland"]
>>CreateSentence(my_list)
'You will like to visit Atlanta as city 1 and NewYork as city 2 and Portland as city 3'
```

Comment: This does not handle an arbitrary list, it is restricted to exactly two cities.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to write your functions in a generic way. Here is one way to make it work for any number of cities.

```
def buildString(cities):
    prefix = "You would like to visit "
    suffix = " on your trip"
    if len(cities) == 0:
        return "No places to visit"
    elif len(cities) == 1:
        return prefix + cities[0] + suffix
    else:
        k = [ city + ' as city ' + str(count+1) for count, city in enumerate(cities)]
        output = prefix + ", ".join(k[:-1]) + " and " + k[-1] + suffix
        return  output
```

**Test:**

```
>>> buildString(["Dallas"])
'You would like to visit Dallas on your trip'
>>> buildString(["Dallas","Houston"])
'You would like to visit Dallas as city 1 and Houston as city 2 on your trip'
>>> buildString(["Dallas","Houston","Sanjose"])
'You would like to visit Dallas as city 1, Houston as city 2 and Sanjose as city 3 on your trip'
```